# Can I make in react.js custom animations, using only JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am wondering if is possible, in React.js, to make animations from scratch using only JavaScript and CSS. And if it is possible can someone direct me to some documentation or tell me how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes this is possible with CSS animations or even transitions, but this question is very vague and has no specific problem to solve. I suggest spending more time searching Google, or checking message boards and chat rooms before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. Well for example I have used react-reveal to make parts of my site fade in from the bottom, but their travel distance is fixed. This library recommends not to use their prop distance since is experimental. I was wondering if there is any way I can use IntersectionObserver API instead, directly in react?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **styled-components** library. Styled Components is an alternative CSS enhancement for designing components in React.

You can read the documentation about the library's animations [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#animations).